# How to remove hyperlinks in a string, but keep images only?

Tags: php

How do I  remove hyperlinks in a string in PHP , and keep images only?

for example:

```
1 - <img src="https://image.jpg" />

2 - <a href="https://URL">Link text</a>

3 - <a href="https://URL"><img src="https://image.jpg" /></a>
```

I want to keep only number 1 in the example, remove link in number 2, but keep text; and remove hyperlink in number 3 with keeping this part only:

`<img src="https://image.jpg" />`

I used this code:

```
$URLContent = preg_replace('#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $URLContent);
```

but this removes all links within string including photos!

Comment: it's not a safe approach to user regex to parse html. May I ask why you have html strings to manipulate at that stage? maybe there's another way. In case there isn't you may consider the `DOMDocument::loadHTML` https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php that will return an object you can manipulate more safely

Comment: This comes from rss feed

Comment: You could use an XML parser then

Comment: I want a php code

Comment: Yes well there are xml parsers for php. Please do some basic research

Comment: _"remove link in number 2, but keep text;"_ - So "keep images only" as it says in the title isn't accurate? Or is the title accurate and the text in the question wrong? Please edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Since regular expression are not an appropriate tool to safely parse html, it's better to use `DOMDocument` and its `loadHTML` method:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Here we have a function `UnwrapAnchorsContent` that will parse a passed string looking for anchor elements and for each one of those it will extract its content, appending it to the anchor's parent and removing the anchor itself.

It's worth saying that since `$doc->saveHTML()` would return the whole html according to the newly created DOMDocument held in `$doc`, we are in the position to return instead the first child in the `body` element. This will work correctly as long as we are not passing a whole `<body>` to the function.

Apart from that condition, ***this function should work with any html given***, even if there were anchors containing any arbitrary content beyond just an `<img>` element. The html content passed it's not limited to a single anchor element but could be a whole list or even more than just that.

***That's also why insisting on parsing it with a regular expression would be a huge mistake and would sooner or later brings problems.***

Here's the working demo https://onlinephp.io/c/a0741

```
<?php

$htmlSamples = [
    '<img src="https://image.jpg" />',
    '<a href="https://URL">Link text</a>',
    '<a href="https://URL"><img src="https://image.jpg" /></a>'
];

foreach($htmlSamples as $html)
    echo UnwrapAnchorsContent($html) . "\n";

function UnwrapAnchorsContent($html){
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
      $parentNode = $anchor->parentNode;
      while ($anchor->hasChildNodes()) {
        $parentNode->appendChild($anchor->firstChild);
      }
      $parentNode->removeChild($anchor);
    }
    $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    return $doc->saveHTML($body->childNodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but I don't want an array. It's a whole text comes from rss feed.

Comment: it was a demo. The focus is not the input array but the function UnwrapAnchorsContent. I fed that function with input coming from an array from the caller but you can use that function anyway you prefer just passing to it a string containing any html.